# Add a hrule to only chapter not numbered

Tags: sectioning, chapters, rules, titlesec, starred-version

I am thinking of adding a `hrule` to only chapters that are not numbered, in other words the chapters created using `chapter*{}`. I thought of using the `titlesec` package- My problem is that I cannot find anything in the documentation about the customizaion of non-numberred (starred) chapters. Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

I guess you have not looked hard enough, it is in the documentation of `titlesec`, look for `numberless`. Try

```
\documentclass{report}

% \usepackage{fncychap}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{name=\chapter}[display]%
  {\bfseries\Large}{Chapter \thechapter}{1em}{}

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]%
  {\bfseries\Large}{}{0pt}{}[\titlerule]

\begin{document}

\chapter{First}

\chapter*{Second}

\chapter{Third}

\end{document}
```

Of course you have to adapt the settings to your likings, and it might happen that `titlesec` and `fncychap` interfere (You didn't specify which `fncychap` settings you use).

Note also that you have to give a definition for the unstarred version, too, as otherwise the setting for the starred version (`numberless`) don't take effect.

Comment: Unfortunately it goes in coflict with fncychap...

Comment: Both the package can't exist

Comment: @Mazzy Bad luck. Maybe that is another question? ;-)

Comment: Maybe...I could try to open another question and see what happen

Answer (score 1):

Redefine `\@makeschapterhead`, for example:

```
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
{\raggedright{\Large\bfseries #1\strut}\par\hrule\nobreak\vskip 10\p@}}
```

Comment: I forgot to say I'm using fncychap to customize the chapter numbered

Comment: Oops. Then I can't help you: I've never used this package (I prefer to do such simple things by hands).