# Using both titlesec and fncychap in the same document

Tags: incompatibility, titlesec, fncychap

I have created my thesis using `fncychap` to customize the chapters. There are also chapters starred created using `chapter*{}`. I would add an `hrule` in those chapters. As the user *mafp* suggested me, it is possible using `titlesec` package. Unfortunately those two packages enter in conflict. Here it is the previosly topic [Add a hrule to only chapter not numbered](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91311/add-a-hrule-to-only-chapter-not-numbered/)

Here it is **MWE**:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[margin=3cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Intro}

\lipsum[1-3]

\chapter{My Chapter}

\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

I would add hrule to the starred chapter Intro without affecting My chapter

Comment: If you wanted to use one of the packages for `\chapter` and the other one for `\section`, I believe it would be possible. But I doubt you can combine their features in one type of sectioning commands.

Comment: A MWE is very essential in this question. Please give an actual use case.

Comment: I think it doesn't matter a MWE. As you can see in the previosly question, it is not possible using both fncychap and titlesec together

Comment: @Mazzy But please provide a MWE with your `fncychap` setup. This was also missing in your last question.

Comment: @Mazzy It's only a waste of time asking questions where you don't give enough details of what you want to do. If you specify which of the chapter styles provided by `fncychap` you're using, it's probably possible to find a way to do what you'd like. But so long as this question is in the present format, it is not a real question.

Comment: Ok I'm preparing a MWE showing the real problem...

Comment: Posted MWE showing what I want exact realize

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change the definition of `\@makeschapterhead`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=3cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
\makeatletter
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent\z@\raggedright\normalfont\interlinepenalty\@M
   \DOTIS{#1}%
   \vskip-30\p@ 
   \kern-.4\p@
   \hrule
   \vskip70\p@}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Intro}

\lipsum[1-3]

\chapter{My Chapter}

\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

It's a bit difficult to follow what `fncychap` does with `\DOTIS`, but you can move the line up and down by modifying `-30\p@` (which stands for -30pt) and `70\p@` (the sum should be 40 to maintain the same distances).

Just a personal note: I find the Lenny chapter style preposterously horrible. But it's only an opinion, of course.

Comment: Yeah now it works.. egreg I agree with you about the style but Lenny style is the most nice style I found among styles offered by fncychap package. Do you have another idea of style to use for a thesis?

Comment: @Mazzy Use the plain book style. It's surely many times superior to Lenny (according to my tastes). And no, no other style provided by the package catches me.